# How to detect during Tick event if a dialog is open in Word?

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

In the interest of doing a https://stackoverflow.com/q/27159229/1168342 I am using a timer event to update the ribbon based on the paragraph style of where the cursor is.

However, if the user opens a dialog (e.g., **Define New Number Format** inside a numbered paragraph)

[image]

an exception occurs, `{"Cannot create a Selection object when this dialog is active."}`, inside the timer event when trying to obtain the selection:

```
If Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection.Type <> WdSelectionType.wdSelectionInlineShape Then
```

Any access to `Application.Selection` causes the exception (even checking it for `Nothing`). So, I'm wondering how can I detect if a dialog is open?

---

**Edit** A workaround is to catch the `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException` when trying to get `Globals.ThisDocument.Application.Selection`. However, it seems better not to access this if a dialog is up and avoid the exception altogether.

Comment: Did you ever manage to figure this out?

Comment: @SameerSingh No. If I remember well, I used a polling loop rather than a tick event. It's CPU usage is minimal, but not as efficient as events. It also affects​the cursor blinking behavior....

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to access the Word object model from secondary threads. But you shouldn't do so because Office applications uses the single threaded apartment model and doesn't support multithreading. You have to work with Word object on the main thread (UI thread). Use the timer class which fires the Tick event on the main thread (not secondary). See [Comparing the Timer Classes in the .NET Framework Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) for more information.

Comment: What makes you think it's a thread issue? Also, when I click the link, I wind up on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/default.aspx (it's a redirect).

Comment: I tried using `System.Timers.Timer` instead of `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` but the problem is the same. I don't think this has anything to do with threading. The problem is that when a dialog is in front, there is no `Application.Selection` (the error makes sense to me). I'm trying to understand how to detect if a dialog is open or how to detect if an Application.Selection is invalid.